# Xcode error: *|synchronize-skip|* a fence was started inside of a snapshot block

Tags: xcode, swift, uitextfield

I have an app that has a textfield. When I run in, tap the textfield, put the app in the background (by tapping the Home button, of course), I get the following error:

> 2016-05-05 00:09:34.874 BugTesting[428:48526]  *|synchronize-skip|* a
>   fence was started inside of a snapshot block - skipping the workspace
>   synchronize because it may dequeue messages from the fenceExemptQueue
>   and snapshots expect that not to happen 2016-05-05 00:09:35.081
>   BugTesting[428:48526]  *|synchronize-skip|* a fence was started inside
>   of a snapshot block - skipping the workspace synchronize because it
>   may dequeue messages from the fenceExemptQueue and snapshots expect
>   that not to happen

Exact process for what I did to get this error:
1) Created a single view app.
2) Went to the main.storyboard and dragged in a textfield to the center of the default view.
3) Control + dragged from the textfield to the top of the viewcontroller and made the viewcontroller the textfield's delegate.
4) Went to ViewController.swift
   a) Added an IBOutlet for the textfield
   b) Made the ViewController class conform to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol.
5) Went back to main.storyboard and connected the IBOutlet to the textfield in the IB.
6) Then, ran the app on my iPad. 
7) When I ran the app and put it in the background without tapping the textfield, I didn't get errors.
8) **When I tapped the textfield, and the keyboard was open, then put the app in the background by pressing the home button, I got the error.**

I went through that explanation, since I figured ya'll might be able to recreate it.

Why does this happen? Is it because I'm doing something wrong, or is it a bug?

Comment: What's your question though?

Comment: Whoops, that's a good point.

Comment: @pbush25 Is this just a bug in iOS, or am I doing something wrong?